# refresh the page + go to another anchor in the same time

Tags: jquery, html, page-refresh

I am trying to apply a script or a tag which does two things. Refreshes the current page and go to another anchor on the same page:

```
<a class="link" href="TheSamePage#differentAnchor">Refresh and go</a>
```

Is that even possible?

I have a huge script which contains some additional actions on this page:[Problematic page](http://content.captive-portal.com/cosmo/problem/)

The problem is when you click on e.g. first button and play the video, then click back - the video is still playing in the background.

When I reload the page it stops playing.
When I point BACK button to the same file, it recognizes the page as the same one and doesn't reload it. How to overcome this problem?

Comment: @dwhite.me that won't refresh the page.

Comment: What about something like `href="TheSamePage?dummy=somethingrandom#differentAnchor"`?

Comment: @putvande this doesn't refresh the page unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, sorted.
It can be done by using an image:

```
<img class="mainm" src="img.png" />
```

and jquery

```
<script>
    $('.mainm').click(function(){
      window.location = 'index.html';
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a `window.location.reload()` after you set the url.

```
<a class="link" href="TheSamePage#differentAnchor" onclick="window.location.href=this.href;window.location.reload();">Refresh and go</a>
```

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work. The problem is that the page contains many different scripts, which perform return animation. Very hard to explain. Probably that's why i got downvoted so much